# Wrapping <a> around <div>, <figcaption> is invalid

Tags: css, html

I have a grid with grid items and I wrapped them in < a > tags so that the entire element leads to  the link. I really want valid html.

```
          <!--Grid Item-->
          <figure class="grid-item">
              <span>
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="images/image.jpg">
                  <figcaption>
                      <h1>Title</h1>
                      <p>Description</p>
                  </figcaption>
                  <div class="item-background"></div>
                </a>
              </span>
          </figure>
          <!--End Grid Item-->
```

In certain hover effects the item background and ficaption are over the image with a lot of the image being exposed and left without the link.
I have created a lot of hover effects with this structure. I know this is valid in html5 but I want to come up error free in html4 validator. Plus, I hear it's bad practice. I don't want to add any javascript if possible.

Should I keep it the way I have it now or is there a valid way that doesn't interfere with the design.

Comment: If you want this to be valid html4, the only choice is to not use `figure` and `figcaption` at all, nor block elements inside `a`.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure what exactly you're referring to with the bad practice. If people are telling you to not use something because it is invalid HTML4, or because it is invalid XHTML, please ignore them.

Comment: *I want to come up error free in html4 validator* - May I ask why? Are you supporting a really old browser?

Comment: @Mr Lister I googled the topic and came across all sorts of comments. If this is acceptable and not looked down upon then i'm satisfied.

Comment: @BSMP ie9+, chrome, firefox, safari

Comment: All of those browsers support HTML5. Whether or not this is bad practice is an opinion based discussion, though there's an interesting Meta question related to this here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316022/please-keep-the-links-vimium-compatible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know this is valid in html5

Then you can make it valid by marking your document as HTML 5.

… or you could if that was correct. You also need to move the anchor so it is either entirely within the `figcaption` or entirely around the `figure`.

> but I want to come up error free in html4 validator.

That won't happen.

- HTML 4 does not support block elements in anchors.
- HTML 4 does not support figure elements.
- HTML 4 does not support figcaption elements.

If you want to use features introduced into HTML this century, then you need to use a specification for HTML that was written this century.

> I don't want to add any javascript if possible.

Injecting the content with JavaScript instead of putting it in the HTML would make the HTML valid. But that would be a terrible hack that misses the point of using a validator in the first place.

Comment: I still get errors. Error: Element figcaption not allowed as child of element a in this context.

Comment: @CarlosSalazar — Ah. I shouldn't haven't trusted your statement that it was allowed in HTML then :) I've just checked the spec. Figcaption must be a child (not another kind of descendant) of the figure. Wrap the anchor around the whole thing, or around the contents of the figcaption.

Answer (score 0):

In W3C Standards Compliant `HTML 4.01` and `xHTML 1.0`, `<a>` is an inline element.

It cannot include a nested block-level element.

The only way to have this validate as W3C Standards Compliant `HTML 4.01` is to include repeated anchors around the image, around the `<h1>` and the `<p>`, inside the `<div>` etc.